# How to add subtitles to a group of plots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, captions, subcaption

I have the following group of plots:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={
                    group name=my plots,
                    group size=2 by 2,
                    xlabels at=edge bottom,
                    ylabels at=edge left,
                    horizontal sep=2cm,
                    vertical sep=3cm,
                    },
                symbolic x coords={Hamming loss, Accuracy, F1-score, Score, Recall, Precision, Jaccard similarity, F-Beta score}, 
                xtick=data,
                x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
                ymax=100,
                ymin=10,
                width=0.5\linewidth
            ]
                \nextgroupplot
                    \addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,yellow] coordinates{(Hamming loss,52.44) (Accuracy, 47.55) (F1-score,30.64) (Score,44.94) (Recall,47.55) (Precision, 22.61) (Jaccard similarity, 47.55) (F-Beta score,10.62)};
                \nextgroupplot
                    \addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,yellow] coordinates{(Hamming loss,52.44) (Accuracy, 47.55) (F1-score,30.64) (Score,44.94) (Recall,47.55) (Precision, 22.61) (Jaccard similarity, 47.55) (F-Beta score,10.62)};
                %Sistema para un kernel lineal:
                \nextgroupplot
                    \addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,yellow] coordinates{(Hamming loss,52.44) (Accuracy, 47.55) (F1-score,30.64) (Score,44.94) (Recall,47.55) (Precision, 22.61) (Jaccard similarity, 47.55) (F-Beta score,10.62)};
                    \addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,yellow] coordinates{(Hamming loss,52.44) (Accuracy, 47.55) (F1-score,30.64) (Score,44.94) (Recall,47.55) (Precision, 22.61) (Jaccard similarity, 47.55) (F-Beta score,10.62)};
                \nextgroupplot[legend to name=testLegend]
                    %bolita
                    \addlegendentry{text1}
                    \addplot[mark=*,thick,blue] coordinates {(Hamming loss,55.36) (Accuracy,44.63) (F1-score,27.55) (Score,46.63) (Recall,44.63) (Precision, 19.26) (Jaccard similarity, 44.63) (F-Beta score,10.03)};
                    %rombo
                    \addlegendentry{text1 + text2}
                    \addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,red] coordinates{(Hamming loss,55.12) (Accuracy,44.87) (F1-score,27.80) (Score,46.65) (Recall,45.0) (Precision, 20.20) (Jaccard similarity, 44.87) (F-Beta score,10.00)};
                    %linea punteada
                    \addlegendentry{text1 + text2 + text3}
                    \addplot[mark=o,mark options={solid},black,thick,dashed] coordinates {(Hamming loss,54.89) (Accuracy, 45.10) (F1-score,28.04) (Score,46.14) (Recall,45.0) (Precision, 20.34) (Jaccard similarity, 45.10) (F-Beta score,10.20)};
                    \addlegendentry{text1 + text2 + text3 + text4}
                    \addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,yellow] coordinates{(Hamming loss,52.44) (Accuracy, 47.55) (F1-score,30.64) (Score,44.94) (Recall,47.55) (Precision, 22.61) (Jaccard similarity, 47.55) (F-Beta score,10.62)};
            \end{groupplot}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \ref{testLegend}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

I would like to add some subtitles for each plot, for example something like this:

```
    Title                        Title
--------------             ----------------
-            -             -              -
-            -             -              -
-            -             -              -
-            -             -              -
--------------             ----------------


    Title                       Title
--------------             ----------------
-            -             -              -
-            -             -              -
-            -             -              -
-            -             -              -
--------------             ----------------
```

I tried with adding a `\caption{}` to each one of this plots, the problem is that when I add some caption it mess up all the tikz figure. For example the plots overlie each other, any idea of how to aproach this issue?, I guess this situations is probably by the floats. Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when i add a title to each of the plots in the group like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={
                    group name=my plots,
                    group size=2 by 2,
                    xlabels at=edge bottom,
                    ylabels at=edge left,
                    horizontal sep=2cm,
                    vertical sep=3cm,
                    },
                symbolic x coords={Hamming loss, Accuracy, F1-score, Score, Recall, Precision, Jaccard similarity, F-Beta score}, 
                xtick=data,
                x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
                ymax=100,
                ymin=10,
                width=0.5\linewidth
            ]
                \nextgroupplot[title=Top Left]
                    \addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,yellow] coordinates{(Hamming loss,52.44) (Accuracy, 47.55) (F1-score,30.64) (Score,44.94) (Recall,47.55) (Precision, 22.61) (Jaccard similarity, 47.55) (F-Beta score,10.62)};
                \nextgroupplot[title=Top Right]
                    \addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,yellow] coordinates{(Hamming loss,52.44) (Accuracy, 47.55) (F1-score,30.64) (Score,44.94) (Recall,47.55) (Precision, 22.61) (Jaccard similarity, 47.55) (F-Beta score,10.62)};
                %Sistema para un kernel lineal:
                \nextgroupplot[title=Bottom Left]
                    \addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,yellow] coordinates{(Hamming loss,52.44) (Accuracy, 47.55) (F1-score,30.64) (Score,44.94) (Recall,47.55) (Precision, 22.61) (Jaccard similarity, 47.55) (F-Beta score,10.62)};
                    \addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,yellow] coordinates{(Hamming loss,52.44) (Accuracy, 47.55) (F1-score,30.64) (Score,44.94) (Recall,47.55) (Precision, 22.61) (Jaccard similarity, 47.55) (F-Beta score,10.62)};
                \nextgroupplot[title=Bottom Right,legend to name=testLegend]
                    %bolita
                    \addlegendentry{text1}
                    \addplot[mark=*,thick,blue] coordinates {(Hamming loss,55.36) (Accuracy,44.63) (F1-score,27.55) (Score,46.63) (Recall,44.63) (Precision, 19.26) (Jaccard similarity, 44.63) (F-Beta score,10.03)};
                    %rombo
                    \addlegendentry{text1 + text2}
                    \addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,red] coordinates{(Hamming loss,55.12) (Accuracy,44.87) (F1-score,27.80) (Score,46.65) (Recall,45.0) (Precision, 20.20) (Jaccard similarity, 44.87) (F-Beta score,10.00)};
                    %linea punteada
                    \addlegendentry{text1 + text2 + text3}
                    \addplot[mark=o,mark options={solid},black,thick,dashed] coordinates {(Hamming loss,54.89) (Accuracy, 45.10) (F1-score,28.04) (Score,46.14) (Recall,45.0) (Precision, 20.34) (Jaccard similarity, 45.10) (F-Beta score,10.20)};
                    \addlegendentry{text1 + text2 + text3 + text4}
                    \addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,yellow] coordinates{(Hamming loss,52.44) (Accuracy, 47.55) (F1-score,30.64) (Score,44.94) (Recall,47.55) (Precision, 22.61) (Jaccard similarity, 47.55) (F-Beta score,10.62)};
            \end{groupplot}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \ref{testLegend}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

i get this:

[image: withTitles]

do you get something different/is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: I did not was aware of the `title=` parameter at the `\nextgroupplot`

Comment: @ml_guy anytime; pgfplots is one of my favorites